# How to add jdbc dependency to Play project?

Tags: scala, jdbc, sbt, playframework-2.2

I'm using `play 2.2.2`.

I'd like to enable `jdbc` library in a Play/Scala project as mentioned in [Accessing an SQL database](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaDatabase).

Here's my `rootproject/project/plugins.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc
  "com.google.zxing"   %  "core"                 % "2.0",
  "mysql"              %  "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.27",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick"                % "2.1.0",
  "org.slf4j"          %  "slf4j-nop"            % "1.6.4"
)
```

While compiling the project, I get following `jdbc` not found error,

```
$ /usr/local/play-2.2.2/play compile
/packup/smartad-core/project/plugins.sbt:8: error: not found: value jdbc
      jdbc
          ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

My `rootproject/build.sbt` simply is

```
  import play.Project._                                                                                                                               

  name := "smartad-backend"                                                                              

  version := "1.0"                                                                                       

  playScalaSettings
```

### References

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAnorm

Comment: Everything you have here should be in `build.sbt`, not `plugins.sbt`.

Comment: Thx @m-z That's true, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should combine both of those blocks into your `build.sbt` file. `plugins.sbt` is for adding sbt plugins, such as the play sbt plugin. But that's about it.

```
import play.Project._                                                                                                                               

name := "smartad-backend"                                                                              

version := "1.0"                                                                                       

playScalaSettings 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   jdbc,
   ...
)
```